# How to crop from one image and paste into another with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, paste, crop

With PIL, I am trying to copy a rectangle out of an image, and paste it into another. This is my code:

```
import Image
ii = Image.open("ramza.png")
box = (70, 70, 30, 30)
region = ii.crop(box)
io = Image.open("template.png")
io.paste(region, box)
io.save("output.png")
```

And I am getting this error:

> ValueError: images do not match

Do any of you know a fix to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A PIL crop box is defined as a 4-tuple of pixel coordinates: **`(left, upper, right, lower)`**.

To fix your code to get a 30x30 crop:

```
box = (70, 70, 100, 100)
```

Broken down into components:

```
x, y, w, h = (70, 70, 30, 30)
box = (x, y, x + w, y + h)
```

Answer (score 4):

For future visitors: this error may also come up if the `box` argument to `paste` contains `float`s instead of `int`s.

Comment: thanks, this is the worst kind of fail - the intermittent fault! most of the time `paste` works fine with floats, but occasionally it don't..